# Android - 1 divided by 2 = 0

Tags: java, android

I have been trying to use my new IOIO for android, and needed to find a frequency of a signal.
So I converted the signal to binary and then did 1 divided by the time between 1's. Although when I did this I found that I got 0 as my output. I then decided to see what 1 / 2 gave me, and to my surprise it also gave 0! Anyone have any idea why this is the case?

Code:
     `private float frequency = 1/2;`

Could this be todo with using `Float.toString(frequency)`?

Comment: Please note that this behavior is not Android-specific; the behavior would be the same in a "normal" Java program.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is an example of integer division. Try:

```
private float frequency = 1.0/2.0;
```

Java will execute 1/2, which yields 0.5. However, since Java sees this as operations on integers (and 0.5 isn't an integer), it'll truncate the decimal and leave just the integer part, 0. By telling Java to work with floats (1.0 vs. 1), you tell it to keep the decimal part of the intermediate computation.

Comment: It's important to realize that the expression to the right of the assignment is evaluated as written regardless of the type of the variable the result is being assigned to.  In this case, integer literals were being used, so the result of the expression is an integer, which is then cast/converted to a float.

Answer (score 5):

1 and 2 are integers in java.  If you want them to be explicitly interpreted as floats you need to do.

```
private float frequency = 1f/2f;
```

If you don't care if the math is actually done on a double first, then just this is easier to read:

```
private float frequency = 1.0/2.0;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is integer division (only whole numbers).

Try:

```
private float frequency = 1/2.0;
```

Answer (score 1):

the 1 and 2 are integers, and they return an integer.

Try creating two floats with those values before doing the division.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ***cast***. Here is ***[more information](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1170)***

`float myValue = (float) 1/2;`

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        float myValue = (float) 1/2;
        System.out.println("1/2 = " + myValue);
    }
}
```

Output would be `1/2 = 0.5`

Answer (score 0):

When you do aritmetic with integers the resul becomes an integer also add .0

so

```
private float frequency = 1.0/2.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
    private float frequency = 1F/2F;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are dividing two integers and you are not getting the correct output just caste the evaluated `int` result to `float` as shown below.

```
    int b = 2;
    int a = 1;

    float out = (float) a / b;
    System.out.println(out);
```

This will produce the output 0.5